# How to get this complete line of file in list using robot framework?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I saved one output in Test1.txt like below.

Test1.txt:-

```
sq.service - SYSV: sudha md server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/md; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-01-13 21:06:14 JST; 5 months 0 days ago
     docs: man:systemd-mon-gator(8)
```

And I got the output like that by executing the command.

```
***Test Cases***

Check the Regular Expresssion
    ${Cmd_Output}=  Get File  Test1.txt
${matches}=  String.Get Regexp Matches    ${Cmd_Output}  (?s).*(Active):\\s*(\\w+).*;\\s*(\\d)\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(\\d+)\\s*(\\w+)  1  2  3  4  5  6
    log to console  ${matches}
```

I got ouput like that:

```
Check the Regular Expresssi                                           ..[('Active', 'active', '5', 'months', '0', 'days')]
Check the Regular Expresssi                                           | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is any optmized way to get this comlete line "Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-01-13 21:06:14 JST; 5 months 0 days ago" in a list in robot framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following keywords from [string library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Line) of robot framework -
`Get Line` and `Split to Lines`

***1.*** - More close to what you want you can split this output using `split string` keyword to get it into list.

```
*Test Cases
Check the Regular Expresssion
    ${Cmd_Output}=  Get File    ${filepath}
    ${Lines}            Get Line    ${Cmd_Output}   2 
    log to console  ${Lines}
```

**Output** -

```
==============================================================================
Check the Regular Expresssion                                         ..   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-01-13 21:06:14 JST; 5 months 0 days ago
Check the Regular Expresssion                                     | PASS |
```

***2.*** - Another way to suffice your requirement.

```
*Test Cases
    Check the Regular Expresssion
        ${Cmd_Output}=  Get File    ${filepath}
        @{Lines}=           Split To Lines       ${Cmd_Output}
        log to console  ${Lines}
```

**Output** -

```
==============================================================================
Check the Regular Expresssion                                         ..['sq.service - SYSV: sudha md server daemon', '   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/md; bad; vendor preset: disabled)', '   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-01-13 21:06:14 JST; 5 months 0 days ago', '     docs: man:systemd-mon-gator(8)']
Check the Regular Expresssion                                         | PASS |
```